# One MSI for both per-user and per-machine installation?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Using `WiX 3.8`. Is it possible to create **one** MSI that allows for both per-user and per-machine installations? I want my installer to detect if elevation is required, preferably after the user has selected the installation directory.

**These are my requirements:**

1. Support for Windows 7 or later.
2. One MSI for both per-user and per-machine installations.
3. No Setup.exe (bootstrapper).
4. No elevation prompt if not required. E.g. Installing to `%LOCALAPPDATA%`.
5. Elevation prompt shown if required. E.g. Installing to `%PROGRAMFILES%`.

A possible compromise would be to skip the 5th requirement and call for explicit elevation before the Setup is started, but I really want to avoid such hassle.

**So far, I have this:**

```
<Package InstallerVersion="405"
         InstallPrivileges="limited"
         InstallScope="perUser" AdminImage="no" ... />

<Condition Message="Setting the ALLUSERS property is not allowed...">
    Installed OR (NOT ALLUSERS)
</Condition>
```

All `KeyPath` entries are mapped to `HKMU`.

**Can this be done?**

I have googled this several times and have not been able to find a complete answer. Can the above be accomplished? `WiX` gurus, please help!

Answer (score 1):

[Single Package Authoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408068(v=vs.85).aspx) is what MS call this. It should be possible in WiX, it's a Windows Installer thing.

Comment: Don't you need a bootstrapper EXE to get this working?

Comment: Yes, you need a bootstrapper EXE :P